# Need help understanding what the term fiber means concerning functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I've got the following sets, the first 1. being the image of $f$.

1. $f(A)=\{b\in{B}\ |\ b=f(a)$, for some $a\in{A}$}

The second 2. is the preimage of $C$ under $f$, which consists of the elements of $A$ mapping into $C$ under $f$.

2. $F^{-1}(C)=\{a\in{A}\ |\ f(a)\in{C}\}$

Everything above I understand very clearly. I'm confused by what follows.

For each $b\in{B}$, the preimage of $\{b\}$ under $f$ is called the **fiber** of $f$ over $b$.

Any intuition here would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: The fiber of $\{b\}$ is the set $\{a\in A\mid f(a)=b\}$.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos! If you could put this as a reply so I can mark this as solved, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiber is as you wrote, the preimage of $\{b\}$ with respect to $f$. In wother words,$$\text{fiber of }\{b\}=\{a\in A\mid f(a)=b\}.$$

Comment: Thank you again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.